# How to configure nginx to use two locations for specific conditions

Tags: nginx, webdav

I have two locations:

```
location ~ ^/[^/]+/[^/]+/reg/.*$ {
    dav_methods DELETE MOVE;
    ...
}

location ~ ^/[^/]+/[^/]+/.*$ {
    dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL MOVE PROPFIND;
    ...
}
```

Basically first one should do something-1 (read-only) for MOVE and DELETE requests on files in /reg/ directory, and the second should do something-2 for all requests on all files including those in /reg/ directory. The thing is that I need something-2 to be done for all requests/files including MOVE and DELETE requests and files from /reg/ directory. How can I do that?

I tried copying code from second location into first one, but PUT, MCKOL and PROPFIND requests are ignored. I also trying to use if (yeah, I know, if is evil, but I'm desperate):

```
location ~ ^/[^/]+/[^/]+/reg/.*$ {
    if ($request_method ~* MOVE) {
        ...-from-loc-1
    }
    ...-from-loc-2
}
```

but ...-from-loc-2 was processed somehow incorrect.

So, any ideas?